# How notifyDataSetChanged ArrayAdapter from dialog?

Tags: android

I set a mydapter for listview in onCreate as:

```
    ArrayAdapter mydapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   mydapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.grid002);
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list002);
            list.setAdapter(mydapter);

}
```

I create a dialog as:
    private void showDiaglogE003() {

```
        try {
            final Dialog dialoge3;
            dialoge3 = new Dialog(this);            
            dialoge3.setContentView(R.layout.layoutdialoge003);         
            Button btnCacnel = (Button) dialoge3.findViewById(R.id.btnE3Cancel);
            btnCacnel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     dialoge3.cancel();
                    mydapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
    dialoge3.show();
}
```

but when i call `notifyDataSetChanged` of mydapter, listview don't change.
Can you help me?

Comment: I'm assuming you're actually setting that adapter into the listview before calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.